# Is there any named pattern for composing a pojo according to parameter passed?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need a factory like method that popoulate the same object according to parameter passed. Something like this:

```
Car output = CarFactory.getCar(EnumCarType.FAST_CAR)
```

**CarFactory**

```
public static Car getCar(EnumCarType type) {

    Car car= new Car();

    switch (type) {
        case FAST_CAR:
            car.setSpeed(200);
            car.setGears(7);
            ...
            break;
        case SLOW_CAR:
            car.setSpeed(120);
            car.setGears(5);
            ...
            break;
    }

    return car;
}
```

As you can see is not a properly factory because I need to return only one type of object so I don't need any kind of abstraction.

Can you help me identifying the right pattern case?

Comment: I believe its still a factory pattern that you are looking for.

Comment: More specifically, the [factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: I agree with the above, and also note that your method is allowed to return a Car instance for each enum _or_ a FastCar, SlowCar, etc. You happen to know that it doesn't, but it's allowed to. The pattern refers to the delegation of the creation/configuration logic, not necessarily that you'll get different concrete types out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the builder pattern. Builder pattern used to build a single type with various parameter https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern